# Как прочитать string после чтения основного типа

Tags: c++

Заранее извиняюсь за идиотизм вопроса.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int IntVar;
    string s;
    cin >> IntVar;
    getline(cin, s);
    return 0;
}
```

функция getline не работает, как я понимаю она берет данные из потока cin, который вызывался ранее, как это обойти и нормально пользоваться getline() или просто прочитать строку с пробелами?